# About the existence of a stationary distribution

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory

> Define $\bar{\pi}(y):=\mathbb{E}_z\{\text{number of visits to } y \text{ before returning to } z\}$, why we have $$\bar{\pi}(y)\leq\mathbb{E}_z\tau_z^{+}$$
>   ?
>   where $\tau_z^{+}:=\min\{t\geq1: X_t=z\}$

I feel like they are equal because $\mathbb{E}_z\tau_z^{+}$ is including the number of visits to $y$ before returning to $z$.

Also, why $$\mathbb{E}_z\{\text{number of visits to } y \text{ before returning to } z\}=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}_z(X_t=y, \tau_z^{+}>t)$$
I can understand the meaning but to get it rigorous. Is it from:
$$\mathbb{E}Y=\sum_{t\geq 0}\mathbb{P}(Y\geq t), Y\geq 0?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, suppose $X_t = z$ and $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{t-1}$ are all $\neq z$ (i.e. we're conditioning on $\tau_z^+ = t$)  Then the number of visits to $y$ before returning to $z$ is equal to the number of $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{t-1}$ that equals $y.$  This is obviously less than $t$ and could be less than $t-1$ if $y$ isn't the only other point in the space.

For your second question, that formula just comes from counting visits.  That is
$$\text{number of visits to } y \text{ before returning to } z = \sum_{t=1}^\infty 1(X_t = y \text{ and } X_s \neq z, \forall s\in[1, t])$$
When we take expectations, we use linearity and $\mathbb{E}[1(A)] = \mathbb{P}(A)$